# C# generic implicit cast on Interface failed

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, casting

Why will the below not compile? What's special about the interface that causes the compiler to think it can't cast from `Container<T>` to `T`, when `T` is an interface? I don't think its a covariant issue, as I'm not downcasting, but perhaps it is. This is quite like [Why C# compiler doesn't call implicit cast operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393701/why-c-compiler-doesnt-call-implicit-cast-operator) but I don't think it's quite the same.

```
Product pIn =null;
Product pOut;
Container<Product> pContainer;

List<Product> pListIn = null;
List<Product> pListOut;
Container<List<Product>> pListContainer;

IList<Product> pIListIn = null;
IList<Product> pIListOut;
Container<IList<Product>> pIListContainer;

pContainer = pIn;
pOut = pContainer; // all good

pListContainer = pListIn; 
pListOut = pListContainer; // all good too

pIListContainer = pIListIn; // fails , cant do implicit cast for some reason
pIListOut = pIListContainer; // and here too
```

---

```
class Container<T>
{
 private T value;

 private Container(T item) { value = item; }

 public static implicit operator Container<T>(T item)
 {
  return new Container<T>(item);
 }

 public static implicit operator T(Container<T> container)
 {
  return container.value;
 }
}
```

---

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Container<IList<Product>>' to 'IList<Product>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
Cannot implicitly convert type 'IList<Product>' to 'Container<IList<Product>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

User defined conversions aren't allowed on interfaces at all. It would potentially be ambiguous, because the type you're trying to convert from could implement the interface itself - at which point what would the cast mean? A reference conversion like a normal cast, or an invocation of the user-defined conversion?

From section 10.3.3 of the C# 4 spec:

> For a given source type S and target type T, if S or T are nullable types, let S0 and T0 refer to their underlying types, otherwise S0 and T0 are equal to S and T respectively. A class or struct is permitted to declare a conversion from a source type S to a target type T only if all of the following are true:
>
> - S0 and T0 are different types.
> - Either S0 or T0 is the class or struct type in which the operator declaration takes place.
> - Neither S0 nor T0 is an interface-type.
> - Excluding user-defined conversions, a conversion does not exist from S to T or from T to S.

and then later:

> However, it is possible to declare operators on generic types that, for particular type arguments, specify conversions that already exist as pre-defined conversions
>   ...
>   In cases where a pre-defined conversion exists between two types, any user-defined conversions between those types are ignored. Specifically:
>
> - If a pre-defined implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from type S to type T, all user-defined conversions (implicit or explicit) from S to T are ignored.
> - If a pre-defined explicit conversion (§6.2) exists from type S to type T, any user-defined explicit conversions from S to T are ignored. Furthermore:
>
>   - If T is an interface type, user-defined implicit conversions from S to T are ignored.
>   - Otherwise, user-defined implicit conversions from S to T are still considered.

Note the first nested bullet here.

(I can *thoroughly* recommend getting hold of the spec by the way. It's available online in [various versions and formats](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Specifications.aspx), but the [hardcopy annotated edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321741765) is also a goldmine of little nuggets from the team and others. I should confess a certain bias here, as I'm one of the annotators - but ignoring my stuff, all the other annotations are well worth reading!)

Comment: interesting interesting.... your point about the type implementing the interface itself makes complete sense now that you've pointed it out. another well deserved drop in your points ocean. i'm waiting on your new in depth book, so ill have to get through it first. ;)

Comment: On the other hand, if S precisely **doesn't** implement the interface T (which is IMHO the only but real interest in making a user-defined conversion from a concrete type to an interface), would there be something left preventing the cast ? Or is it just that the C# compiler team had other fish to fry than dealing with this distinction ?

Comment: @Ssithra: Imagine if S didn't, but some *subtype* of S did... and the actual type at execution time was that subtype... what should happen? Should a user-defined conversion be applied when it's not really needed? Aside from anything else, this feels like a recipe for confusion.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It seems to me that the compiler team had to deal with such a question already : a subtype adds or modifies behaviors of the base type. The conversion method to a given interface could reasonably be considered as a special kind of behavior. When you assign a subtype object to a basetype variable and then call a method on this variable which is redefined in the subtype, the base implementation is considered if the subtype method is a `new` one, and the subtype implementation is considered if the subtype method is an `override` one. Subtle distinction, very different result.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thus, the developer **must** know this distinction, otherwise the result might be different from what he expected. Similarly, the C# compiler team would have to decide if the class to interface conversion should be considered as inherently `new` or `override`. Once decided, the developer would have also to know the decision made to ensure that his code works correctly... Or even better he would have the possibility to explicitely declare his user-defined conversion in the base type as `new` or `override`.

Comment: @Ssithra: If the developer needs to know all possible subclasses, that's breaking Liskov's Substitution Principle. It all sounds like it's introducing a lot of complexity for very little benefit... which is always a warning sign, IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I totally agree with you about the Liskov's Substitution Principle, but can't get the link with my previous comment. I was just making an analogy between a classic method and a conversion method, saying that the rules applying to the first one might be applicable as well to the second. It doesn't sound like adding a lot of complexity, but rather like having the same complexity here and there. Sure, it would require some extra work for the compiler team to achieve that, that's another question. The framework complexity itself would not be increased : just more consistant, no ?

Comment: @Ssithra: It's not a matter of framework complexity - it's complexity in the language, that developers need to learn. Making a language more complex when there's no compelling reason to do so is a *bad idea*.