# Wrapped value extension method / operator

Tags: c#

Say I have generic value wrapper:

```
class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I'd like to use it as listed below (or something like this):

```
var wrapper = new Wrapper<Target>();
// ...
Target target = wrapper;
```

How is it possible using implicit operator, extension method or another approach to provide single-place null checking? As one of benefits I want to keep the following code in the single place:

```
if (wrapper != null)
{
    return wrapper.Value;
}

return default(T);
```

**EDIT:**

I tried the operator:

```
public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> wrapper)
{
    return wrapper.Value ? default(T) : wrapper.Value;
}
```

It's perfectly works I the way below:

```
var wrapper = new Wrapper<long>();
long value = wrapper;
```

But fails on:

```
var wrapper = new Wrapper<IEnumerable<long>>();
IEnumerable<long> value = wrapper;
```

Compiler says it is not possible to convert from `Wrapper<IEnumerable<long>>` to `IEnumerable<long>`. Any ideas?

Comment: what could `T` be here? anything? non-nullable value-type only (aka `where T:struct`)? or...?

Comment: Anything. Are there a number of different solutions for different constraints?

Comment: For value types which are non-nullable, only the wrapper can be null; for reference types, both the wrapper and its value can be null. So you either have one or two checks.

Comment: There is no need to check the `Value`. If it's `== default(T)` then OK let it be returned. No problems here.

Comment: @SergeyMetlov: Does your `Wrapper` class inherit or implement any interfaces (like `IEnumerable<T>`)?

Comment: @SergeyMetlov: Oops, I forgot. Unfortunately, as I understand it, you can't execute user defined conversions on interfaces: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4280626/1269654 (For example, if you change it from `IEnumerable<long>` to `List<long>` the conversion would work.) EDIT: the error message is pretty bad. If you changed it to be _just_ `IEnumerable` (without the generic parameter) it'd say: "user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed"

Answer (score 4):

You can use an implicit operator:

```
public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> value)
{
    return value == null ? default(T) : value.Value;
}
```

**EDIT**:

As @ChrisSinclair has pointed out, this doesn't work when T is interface the only solution a can think of is using an extension method like:

```
public static T SafeGetValue<T>(this Wrapper<T> value)
{
    return value == null ? default(T) : value.Value;
}
```

And then:

```
IEnumerable<long> value = wrapper.SafeGetValue();
```

Comment: Please see my EDIT in question above.

Answer (score 0):

```
return wrapper.Value ?? default(T);
```

Comment: `wrapper` can be null.

Comment: @SergeyMetlov yeah didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

The null-checking could be done in the generic wrapper itself as follows.

```
class Wrapper<T>
{
    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
       get
       {
         return _value ?? default(T);
       }
       set
       {
         _value = value;
       };
    }
}
```

Comment: The main idea is to check `Wrapper` is not null.