# c# Implicit conversion using interface (IList)

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I have implicit conversion for returning **DomainResult**

```
public static implicit operator DomainResult<TEntity>(TEntity resultData)
{
    var result = new DomainResult<TEntity>
    {
        Result = resultData,
        Succeeded = true
    };

    return result;
}
```

when I try to use implicit conversion via `IList`, it is giving me compile time error stating

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>' to
'...DomainResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>'.
   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

.

```
        IList<string> str = new PagedList<string>() { "example" };
        DomainResult<IEnumerable<string>> dr = str; // I am getting compile time error

        List<string> str = new PagedList<string>() { "example" };
        DomainResult<IEnumerable<string>> dr = str; //this is valid
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why would you go trough IList? Why not straight to IEnumerable ?

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280592/c-sharp-generic-implicit-cast-on-interface-failed User defined conversion isn't allowed for interfaces