# Why implicit conversions don't work in C #

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

Please indicate the cause of ***Error1*** and ***Error2***.

***Error1*** is an error that implicit conversion is not performed when using an interface as the IList type.

***Error2*** is an error in which an int type does not perform an implicit conversion when using a function with an IComparable parameter.

```
class Program
{
    class Test : IComparable
    {
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testList = new List<Test>();
        var testArr = new Test[]{ };

        FunctionList(testList);//***Error1***
        FunctionArr(testArr);

        var intArr = new int[] {};
        FunctionArr(intArr);//***Error2***
    }

    static void FunctionList(IList<IComparable> comparables)
    {
        //..
    }

    static void FunctionArr(IComparable[] comparables)
    {
        //..
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# generic implicit cast on Interface failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280592/c-sharp-generic-implicit-cast-on-interface-failed)

Comment: There is a statement that when T in List<T> is an interface Type, no implicit casting occurs.

Comment: I'm curious about the exact reason, but once I think of it as a C# rule, I'm going over.